# expansion of universe does it create a void

Tags: cosmology, universe, space-expansion

If matter can never be created nor destroyed then as the universe expands surely it would create voids at the centre causing a spherical void to be formed,making the shape of the universe at hollow egg and expand till the universe splits into planes which could then be interpreted as a parallel universe,would this be correct

Comment: Your title carries no useful information right now; I suggest you edit it to reflect your question.

Comment: Everyone asking question here  implicitly seeks for help; there is no need to mention this plus of course with unnecessary CAPS. Title is meant to reflect the query that would be elaborated in the body.

Comment: Also, what is your question?

Answer (score 2):

Matter in our Universe is composed of atoms or similar particles. When the Universe expands, it just means that the density of these particles – the approximate number of particles per unit volume (e.g. a cubic meter) – is decreasing as a function of time.

The simplest approximation that is enough to describe much of cosmology assumes that the density of these particles is indeed uniform across the Universe. So they get gradually diluted everywhere, just like when you expand a vessel with gas. The gas (e.g. the air) gets thinner and thinner and the pressure goes down but you never create voids. The matter in the Universe shouldn't be imagined as a "solid" or a "liquid". It's a gas.

In reality, matter tends to clump gravitationally and by other forces – atoms are combining into stars etc. – and there are "almost empty" voids almost everywhere, in between the stars. But the distribution of stars (or at least of clusters of galaxies) remains quasi-uniform.